# ListIndex out of range, not sure why?

Tags: python

I've tried inserting the value 1 in a few different ways in the list relevant to the position of the tile in the grid and it keeps on telling me i'm out of range? if I am using len I thought the point was that couldn't happen? what am I overlooking here? this is quite a bit easier to do in pyglet for me but it doesn't translate to pygame since they're both window managers. thank you guys for your time.

```
import pygame
import time
import random as rnd
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
flags = SCALED | FULLSCREEN | DOUBLEBUF
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500
SCREEN_WIDTH = 1000
resolution = (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution, flags, 16)
# COLOR SCHEME
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (100, 100, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
cell_width = 5
tick = 0
onelist = []
while running:
    tick = tick+1
    screen.fill(BLUE)
    if tick ==1:
        for row in range(0,SCREEN_WIDTH, cell_width):
            for col in range(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT, cell_width):
                square_coords = ((row*cell_width), (col*cell_width),
                                (SCREEN_HEIGHT/(cell_width/4)), (SCREEN_WIDTH/(cell_width/4)))
                if rnd.random() < .6:
                    onelist[row].insert(len(onelist[row]), 1)
                if rnd.random() >= .6 and rnd.random() < .8:
                    onelist[row].insert(len(onelist), 2)
                else:
                    onelist[row].insert(len(onelist), 0)
```

Comment: Suppose `x = [3, 0, -1, 5]`. What is `len(x)`? What is the index value of `5`?

Comment: it would be the listindex error. so should i just start with a populated list of zeros and then .remove() and .append() the data as needed? when I try to do that, it throws an "int object is not callable" error when it's formatted as a list

Comment: Not exactly, errors are what happens when you try to do something the computer doesn't understand. In this case it is throwing a ```ListIndexError``` because you are trying to access an index that doesn't exist.

Comment: so, say I use a text file to hold the value of each index, and it's populated with just zeros, and I use .remove() and .insert(), it should work provided I have enough values filled to cover every iteration of my index right?

Comment: You *could* but I think you'd find that way harder than just learning how to index appropriately. I don't know your use case, but that would make things much harder to debug and understand, not to mention the unnecessary file operations, CPU cycles, and wasted storage space spent on unused zeroes and such. But yeah, you could.

Answer (score 0):

It is very confusing for beginners, especially because it depends on the language, but generally arrays and lists are indexed beginning at zero. This means the first element of any list is [0] and the final element is [len - 1].

What @blorgon is trying to help you to see is that when you check the length of your array, it will be 5 as you expect. But if you just take your list and try to access each element one at a time from 1 - 5, you'll skip the first element and get an error for the last.

So as in the example Blorgon gave,

```
x = [3, 0, -1, 5]
x[0] = 3
x[1] = 0
x[2] = -1
x[3] = 5
# x[4] Doesn't exist
```

Comment: so it should be len(onelist-1), 1)? I'm gonna try that real quick! I get the indexing from 0 thing, but then at that point through the loop if i just used .append(1) shouldn't it just tack the value on to the end as it loops? when I use .append() it also returns an indexerror, same with .insert(1) at a specific index in a populated list

Comment: You're right about the append, but I am willing to bet the append is not what is causing the issue. If you copy and paste the error message into your original post I can help more, but I need more info.